# Catching error in a switch-statement in Python 3?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a switch-statement but I can't get it to write out what I want (`"Error. Please enter the number that represents the activity that the participant would like to do. Only enter one of the following: 1,2,3,4,5,6"`) if the user would enter the wrong key. Someone who knows what I do wrong? (I've only entered a part of the code here but tell me if you think I need to enter more of the code to see where the problem is!) I can run the code and the program gives error if I press the wrong key (not a number) but it does not give the command to the user that I would like to give.

```
def switch():
    x = 0
    x = int(input())

    def cookies(): 
      replit.clear()
      second.Registration()
      informationScout()
      print("Activity chosen: Bake and sell cookies\n")
      second.Continue()

    def bracelets():
      replit.clear()
      second.Registration()
      informationScout()
      print("Activity chosen: Make survival bracelets\n")
      second.Continue()

    def hike():
      replit.clear()
      second.Registration()
      informationScout()
      print("Activity chosen: Night time hike\n")
      second.Continue()

    def swimming():
      replit.clear()
      second.Registration()
      informationScout()
      print("Activity chosen: Swimming\n")
      second.Continue()

    def handicraft():
      replit.clear()
      second.Registration()
      informationScout()
      print("Activity chosen: Handicraft with wood\n")
      second.Continue()

    def ownProposal():
      replit.clear()
      second.Registration()
      informationScout()
      print("Activity chosen: Own proposal\n")
      second.Continue()

    def default():
      print("Error. Please enter the number that represents the activity that the participant would like to do. Only enter one of the folloing: 1,2,3,4,5,6")

    dict = {
      1: cookies,
      2: bracelets,
      3: hike,
      4: swimming,
      5: handicraft,
      6: ownProposal
    }

    dict.get(x,default)()
  switch()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't name a variable `dict` because it shadows the builtin type `dict`

Comment: Also, your code works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0vvL.png, please make sure your [mre] actually reproduces your problem. Did you enter a non-integer instead? That's the only thing that would throw an error (e.g. `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`), in which case you should read a tutorial on try..except statements

Comment: Okay thank you! I changed the name of the variable  dict and did a try-except statement as you said and now it works! But do you know if there is a way to continue the program when it has chatched the error? because now it sais what  I wanted it to say when I press a non-integer, however the program has to stop after that and restart, I wonder if there is a way for the user to make a new try to press an integer instead so the user dont have to restart the program.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because Python is trying to convert something that cant be converted to an integer. You should always check your user input before doing anything with it. For this simple case you could also use a [try except block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), but generally you should find some other way to validate it

I recommend something like this. it will also take care of the other error for the default case.

```py
def get_number_input(min_value, max_value, prompt="", error=""):
    # run until a valid number has been given
    while True:
        # get user input
        user_input = input(prompt)
        # if the user input cannot be interpreted as number...
        if not user_input.isnumeric():
            # print the error
            print(error)
            # and try again
            continue
        # if it can be converted convert the number to an integer
        number = int(user_input)
        # and check if it is inside the given range
        if not min_value <= number <= max_value:
            # if not print the error
            print(error)
            # and retry
            continue
        # otherwise leave the loop
        break
    return number


def switch():
    x = 0
    x = get_number_input(1, 6, "Enter a number ", "Error. Please enter the number that represents the activity that the participant would like to do. Only enter one of the following: 1,2,3,4,5,6")
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Alain T.  and Morgan Kuhles!! very kind, I would like to use these codes but I have to use a try-catch statement, since it is a requirement for an assignment. I dont think I can get in that in this code?  because if I use if-statements, in the way you`ve shown the try-catch wouldn`t be needed in this case no?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to make a switch statement.

First define the switch function:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

Then use it as a single-iteration for-loop where the loop variable is the case() function:

```
for case in switch(x):

    if case(1):  // cookie
        replit.clear()
        second.Registration()
        informationScout()
        print("Activity chosen: Bake and sell cookies\n")
        second.Continue()
        break

    if case(2):  // bracelets
        replit.clear()
        second.Registration()
        informationScout()
        print("Activity chosen: Make survival bracelets\n")
        second.Continue()
        break

    ...

else:
    print("Error. Please enter the number that represents the activity that the participant would like to do. Only enter one of the folloing: 1,2,3,4,5,6")
```

This gives you a much more flexible code structure where you can place common code before and after case blocks and check multiple values in one line.

```
for case in switch(x):

    if not case(1,2,3,4,5,6): continue

    replit.clear()
    second.Registration()
    informationScout()
    
    if case(1):  // cookie
        print("Activity chosen: Bake and sell cookies\n")

    if case(2):  // bracelets
        print("Activity chosen: Make survival bracelets\n")

    ...

    if case(6): // own proposal
        print("Activity chosen: Own proposal\n")

    second.Continue()
    break

else:
    print("Error. Please enter the number that represents the activity that the participant would like to do. Only enter one of the folloing: 1,2,3,4,5,6")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know how to get in the code you made without taking away the try-except statement, but eventually,this code got the program to work as I wanted. Now if I enter a non-int I get to try again, and when I enter an int the program continues and I can eventually return to the menu.

```
def switch():
    x = 0
    while(True):
      try:
        x = int(input())
      except:
        print("Error! Please enter only one of the following numbers when choosing activity 1,2,3,4,5 or 6")
      else:
        def cookies(): 
          replit.clear()
          second.Registration()
          informationScout()
          print("Activity chosen: Bake and sell cookies\n")
          second.ReturnToMenu()

        def bracelets():
          replit.clear()
          second.Registration()
          informationScout()
          print("Activity chosen: Make survival bracelets\n")
          second.ReturnToMenu()

        def hike():
          replit.clear()
          second.Registration()
          informationScout()
          print("Activity chosen: Night time hike\n")
          second.ReturnToMenu()

        def swimming():
          replit.clear()
          second.Registration()
          informationScout()
          print("Activity chosen: Swimming\n")
          second.ReturnToMenu()

        def handicraft():
          replit.clear()
          second.Registration()
          informationScout()
          print("Activity chosen: Handicraft with wood\n")
          second.ReturnToMenu()

        def ownProposal():
          replit.clear()
          second.Registration()
          informationScout()
          print("Activity chosen: Own proposal\n")
          second.ReturnToMenu()

        activitys = {
          1: cookies,
          2: bracelets,
          3: hike,
          4: swimming,
          5: handicraft,
          6: ownProposal
        }
        activitys.get(x)()
        break
  switch()
```